# Determine the number of graphs on the vertex set $\{1, 2, 3 , 4, 5\}$, every vertex is incident to at least one edge.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have the problem of determining how many graphs from the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ there are, given the property that every vertex is incident to at least one edge. The at least one part of the question is what makes me unsure.

I know how to do a similar problem for a specific amount of edges, and have taken the same approach. Using a table where a $1$ represents an edge between vertexes would look like this:

```
  1    2    3    4    5

1 X    0    0    0    0

2 0    X    0    0    0

3 0    0    X    0    0

4 0    0    0    X    0

5 0    0    0    0    X
```

Given that points such as $(1, 2)$ and $(2, 1)$ will always mirror each other on this table we only need to count half the values (the $0$ values about the $X$ line for example).

This gives us

$$\frac{4 \cdot 5}{2}$$

spots to represent edges to choose from, so each possible value will be of the form $C(10, n)$.

Finally, I count each possible number of choices to at least one value for each.

Total number of graphs $= C(10,10) + C(10, 9) + C(10, 8) + C(10, 7) + C(10, 6) + C(10, 5)$

I am not sure this works, I think it might count possibilities with less than one edge. Is my logic correct?

Comment: At least = the graph has only one connected component. You can esaly count the number of possible graphs. Then you can exclude the graphs with $1$ vertex isolated which are $2^6$, this happens $5$ times. You must readd the graphs with two isolated vertex etc. You should apply inclusion-exclusion imo, I'm almost sure but not 100%.

Comment: This seems to work for $n=3$. $2^3 - 3 \cdot 2^1 + (3,2)2^0 - (3,3)=4$.

Comment: @Maffred We're not only talking about connected graphs, the graph with edges $\{12,34,45\}$ should also be counted.

Comment: You are right, my bad!

Comment: What does the (3,2)2^(0) come from?

Comment: It does not exclude unconnected graphs as far as I can tell.

Comment: The way you chose two vertex to let isolated from 3 vertex, multiplied for the numbers of possible graphs. But I answered another question apparently!

Comment: Well I think I counted the right quantity tho! xD Because I made inclusion exclusion for isolated points, that is exactely what I want! Is that right?

Comment: I counted every graph, then I eliminated graphs with one isolated point, then added graphs with 2 isolated points etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n>0$, the total number of graphs on $n$ vertices is $2^{n(n-1)/2}$.  Let $S_k$ be the set of graphs in which vertex $k$ has **no** incident edge.  Then by inclusion/exclusion, the number of graphs you want is
$$|\overline S_1\cap\cdots\cap \overline S_n|
  =2^{n(n-1)/2}-|S_1\cup\cdots\cup S_n|
  =(-1)^n+\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom nk2^{k(k-1)/2}$$
which for $n=5$ works out to $768$.

In fact the sequence is [A006129](http://oeis.org/A006129).